# i class icons showing F0 02 code instead of icon

Tags: wordpress, icons, font-awesome

We're using WPJobster theme and icons through out the website are showing up as code-in-box instead of icon.
Website is https://rawadbiz.com/en/

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbrW9.png)

I'm newbie to wordpress.

Comment: Thats because fonts files are not found. Looking in chrome console there are errors, fount files not found. Are you sure fonts is available in the theme folder at correct path.